# Unit Testing(Mocking) Databases, How To Verify Database Methods With Mocking?

Tags: unit-testing, junit, mocking, mockito, tdd

As a person has no experience before in unit testing and mocking, I followed beginner tutorials about JUnit with Mockito and I do some practice.

Now, I need to unit test some class methods which do basic database operations on a MySQL database. I don't want to make real changes on the database.

In my code:

```
@InjectMocks private DBConnection dbConnection;
@Mock private DBConnection mockDBConnection;

@Test
public void testDropTable() {

    Mockito.when(mockDBConnection.dropTable()).thenReturn(0);

    // dropTable() returns 0 if table dropped
    int result = dbConnection.dropTable();
    Assert.assertEquals(result, 0);
}
```

To verify(with assertEquals() ) result of the test, I am calling real dropTable() method, and it really drops table( Actually it is obvious, because I'm calling on real DBConnection instance)

Is there anyway to verify the methods like that, without accessing the real database? Or did I misunderstand the concept of Unit Testing and Mocking?

Comment: The code seems strange. Why do you have two `DBConnection` objects? You are calling dropTable() on the "real" instance. Does `dbConnection` somehow contain another `DBConnection` field to which it delegates? If not, your code makes no sense, because you create a mock DBConnection and a real one. IF there was a `DBConnection` field in `DBConnection`, this will not work. Perhaps it would be a good idea to provide some `DBConnection` code.

Comment: Yes I have 2 instances. One is the real object, the other one is mock object.

There is no member class in DBConnection class.

DBConnection class have only methods like dropTable(), addEntry() and have private fields which are host, database and port information supplied to DriverManager ( basic JDBC connection)

Comment: Ok that's really explanatory, thank your for the comment. I was also expecting a result like that. But, how I can test my database without touching it? Is there any way for it? Is the only solution creating a test database which has same configuration with development database? As I understood from your comment, I need to drive the real car to be sure it works?

Comment: As soon as your code interacts with another system, there is no way of testing it reliably without having the other system in place. This can be a copy or in-memory version of the database, but everything else would be incomplete. Perhaps there are indirect ways of testing it, but those would require creating highly complex test that, in effect, would probably just simulate a big part of the foreign system. For such stuff, integration tests exist that test how well your system integrates with others.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Imagine the following... You have two cars, one is a real car, another is a fake (mock) car. Now you get into the real car and drive off. Why do you expect not to move? You didn't do anything with the fake car, so even if you told it "Do not move if I start driving", this doesn't change the fact that the real car WILL move when you drive off.

Same thing here, you created a fake DBConnection and a real one. The real one will do whatever the real one does. The fake one can be configured to do different stuff, like you did with Mockito.when(...). But that doesn't change the behavior of the real one.

Your test is effectively meaningless, because your only choice here is to get rid of the mock, because it doesn't serve any meaningful purpose. You do not test a mock. What for? That's like creating a fake car and testing that - it doesn't tell you anything about the real car. You do not need to test the fake car to find out that it will do X if you told it to do X in that test.

There are two ways you can test your DBConnection class:

a) You can connect it to a database and check that it does what it should. This would, of course, be an integration test and not a unit test anymore. In some cases you can use a in-memory database like HSQLDB to speed up this test. But at least in the end you can be reasonably sure that your code does what it is supposed to be doing.

b) IF and only IF DBConnection has some objects internally that do the actual talking to the database, you can, perhaps, mock those and then test DBConnection. Of course, this only moves your problem to another layer, because then you aren't sure that those objects work - you will only know that DBConnection works IF those objects work. While this is good to know, it does not answer the question if your db code will work in the end.

In the end, you can only test db connections completely by connecting to a db. Everything else is not a complete test.

Comment: So it means, I do not need Mocking( it's meaningless) to test if real database connector class works. Mocking just gives "fake" so-called outputs for our inputs.

Comment: Since mocking it completely would require you to effectively simulating a whole DB, it's not really a good plan. Mocking is great if you want to test a unit with all the dependencies mocked - for example, if you have a service that is based on DB data, THEN you can mock the DBConnector and give mock data to the service, because you only want to test what the service does with the data - ensuring that the DBConnector itself works is another problem and should be unit tested seperately.

Comment: Like I need to query a username-password set from a DB to use them in a log-in page. If database didn't completed yet, I can mock and use it to test if my log-in page works without querying the real one(because its not working yet). I'm using mocking to NOT TEST THE MOCKED OBJECT, to TEST THE OBJECT USES MOCK.

Comment: Bingo. You can unit!(!) test your whole login-related under the assumption that the db stuff will work, by providing mocks for the db related objects. The actual db stuff will be (unit?) tested somewhere else. Of course, it's also good then to add integration tests that test all the stuff together to see if they all fit together.

Comment: @FlorianSchaetz FYI,  There is something called sonar scan in big organizations and if  you are working for one ,  then you are expected to do the code coverage (unit tests) .  And if the project is full of jdbc calls ,  it's very difficult to write unit test cases to satisfy sonar.  So the mocking is for the sonar sake.. Something called regulations...If you want to avoid this , we should stop working for a company and have setup our own company.  Entrepreneurship is altogether different topic.

Comment: @Stunner We are working with SonarQube, too (SonarLint also) and it's no problem at all to use tests going to an in-memory db for the coverage of these parts. If your company has regulations that force you to do stupid stuff, then that's a problem of your company, not of companies in general. Doing stuff for sonar's sake is a very stupid thing to do. Understand what sonar tells you and use it as one source of input, but sonar is not the bible to be followed religiously. Ideally you will configure it to suit your needs and not the other way round.

Answer (score 2):

Why not consider using an in-memory database for your unit tests. Maybe using a DAO pattern to easily switch between real and in-memory.

Keep the actual database interaction layer thin as possible to ensure you abstract your logic away in separate classes, this makes testing much easier, as in this case you can mock the DB object and focus on testing your logic.

Also decide what you are testing, most likely you want to test your logic, not the logic of the 3rd party database connector, so focus your tests on that.

Consider a suite of Integration or System tests to test the applications features against a real database, should you require this level of testing, but for unit tests, in-memory should be fine.

The overall confidence of your app can be achieved using be a combination of unit and integration tests.

Comment: I suggested using a In-Memory database to my co-workers, but we agreed on using a test database for the unit tests.

Despite I provided a non-DAO pattern database modeling in my question, we are using DAO approach( I am also not familiar with that). I'm not sure if it will affect the solution I will use. I guess I did not understand purpose of Mocking, but now I understand that. I am not responsible for the whole testing process( I hope), someone else will do integration test as I know.

Answer (score 0):

For the @Florian Schaetz's comment, do I need to do something like that:

AuthenticatorApplicationInterface.java

```
public interface AuthenticatorInterface {

        public boolean authenticateUser(String username, String password) throws EmptyCredentialsException;
}
```

AuthenticatorApplication.java

```
public class AuthenticatorApplication {

    private AuthenticatorInterface authenticator;

    public AuthenticatorApplication(AuthenticatorInterface authenticator)                           {
            this.authenticator = authenticator;
    }

    public boolean authenticate(String username, String password) throws NotAuthenticatedException {
       boolean authenticated;
       authenticated = this.authenticator.authenticateUser(username, password);
        return authenticated;
        }
    }
```

AuthenticatorApplicationTest.java

```
public class AuthenticatorApplicationTest {

        @Test
        public void testAuthenticate() throws EmptyCredentialsException {
            AuthenticatorInterface authenticatorMock;
            AuthenticatorApplication authenticator;
            String username = "username";
            String password = "noncorrectpassword";

            authenticatorMock = Mockito.mock(AuthenticatorInterface.class);
            authenticator = new AuthenticatorApplication(authenticatorMock);

            when(authenticatorMock.authenticateUser(username, password)).thenReturn(false);

            boolean actual = authenticator.authenticate(username, password);

            assertFalse(actual);
    }
}
```