# What do you mean by Unit testing from a developer's point of view.Please don't give the definition.Explain the usage.?

Tags: unit-testing

I am new to programming and i always hear that developer's should do unit testing.There are a lot of definitions available but still i am not clear about it.When someone says a developer do a good unit testing.what exactly he wants me to test??
Let me also tell you that i work in an agile model where we have stories and we unit test every story which we develop.so its just that feature i need to test which is in the story.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You test your functions blackbox to see if the result is as expected. For example let's test the product function. If product(3,4)==12 then our code works but might have bugs. In order to see that the function works properly we have to make multiple tests with floats, integers...

Comment: If i am not wrong you are saying that we need to just test the part which we have developed as part of unit testing.

Comment: Yes, we have to test every function. We can test product with strings to see if we have exceptions. No matter the values received our code musn't crash.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of unit test is to test every part of your code unitary so that you will. For exemple in your software you might have a function that adds two number, so you will have to test it unitary to make sure that when you add up two number in this function it always returns the sum of these two numbers. By unitary I mean that you directly call the function to test it, the function itself must work independently from the rest of the code.

Comment: let's say that as part of requirement i have just added a column in database and i am pulling that value on my UI as a label.So when i write unit test cases for this story i just test whether this particular feature is working or not.correct??

Comment: You can do that for this specific case but it gets a little more complicated when you interact with a database.
Imagine the next step is to change this label, you cannot use the real database for this, I see two choices :
1. You test the connection part and mock the writing part (but it doesn't really test the writing part).
2. You create a specific database (can be in memory) to check if the application interact correctly with the database.

Comment: You can see this post for further detail, I find the answer pretty good : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47547255/unit-testingmocking-databases-how-to-verify-database-methods-with-mocking